# How to set property value from outside pom.xml

Tags: maven

I like to inject from outside the ${project.version} value, this is example pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <version>2020.cool_app-SNAPSHOT</version>
  

    <properties>
        <foo>myapp:${project.version}</foo>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I run:

```
mvn clean install
```

to compile, how can I from outside to set the ${project.version} to the new one? As parameter or something?

Comment: I suggest to read this: https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html

Answer (score 2):

The variables are set as `mvn install -Dprop=value`. Note that there are built-in house-keeping variables like `project.version` - for them to change you need to actually update the `<version>` first:

```
mvn version:set -DnewVersion=1.1.1 clean install
```

This will update `pom.xml` files - if you don't need that you'll have to rollback the changes with your VCS commands.

Alternatively you can define a new property that defaults to the built-in value: `<v>${project.version}</v>`. And then override it:

```
mvn -Dv=1.1.1 clean install
```

Comment: by the way it changes all the jar files and all the artifacts name to the new version name 
this is not what i wanted , how can i prevent it ?
i can't change any think in thepom's